# Learning how to read Javadoc correctly

Tags: java, api, javadoc, analysis, methodology

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly read the JavaDoc page for BigInteger. The part that is particularly confusing deals with the constructor summary

In my book, there is a class example called Rational that has 3 different constructors:

- Rational()
- Rational (int n)
- Rational(int x, int y)

and different methods:

- add
- subtract
- multiply
- divide
- gcd(Greatest common divisor)
- toString.

It has two instance variables:

- int num
- int den

I have to rewrite the Rational class example in my book using:

- BigInteger num
- BigInteger den

  as the instance variables.

The problem is I don't understand:

- how to read the constructor summary
- which to use when I rewrite the Rational class in my book
- what the Field Summary is and what that describes

Am i looking for the parameters in the constructors to select which constructor I want to use? I'm just not sure what I'm reading. Is there a particular technique or method I should be using when reading the Javadoc page for BigInteger?

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: The easiest ways are to use the String constructor: `new BigInteger("123");` and the static `valueOf`: `BigInteger.valueOf(123);`. In your case, the latter seems indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are confused about the `BigInteger` constructors on the javadoc; the truth is, from what you say, you only need the one needed to convert `int` to `BigInteger` (through String)! You just need to change your constructors in `Rational` to use BigInteger. If the `Rational` constructors take in `int` datatypes, simply convert them within the constructor to `BigInteger` type and assign to your `BigInteger` instance variables. If you look at the methods, there are equivalents to the basic operations you need (add, subtract, etc) for the other methods in the class.

EDIT: I'll give a small example. I assume your `Rational(int x, int y)` constructor looks something like this:

```
public Rational (int x, int y) {
    num = x;
    dem = y;
}
```

If `num` and `den` are now BigIntegers, you'll need to change it so x and y are converted to BigIntegers. If you look at the `BigInteger` constructors, there are none that take int directly. But we have `BigInteger(String val)`, and int can be converted to `String`.

```
public Rational (int x, int y) {
    num = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(x));
    dem = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(y));
}
```

With this idea you can figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: Thanks. That was the part that was confusing me. None of the BigInteger constructors on the Javadoc page  took int as an argument so I was confused. =

Answer (score 2):

> how to read the constructor summary

- Copy/Paste the dot notation under java.lang.object and prepend "new  " to create

> which to use when I rewrite the Rational class in my book

- Use the one which matches your data type. If it does not match, use the one which takes a `String`, then use `toString()` to convert what you have

> what the Field Summary is and what that describes

- The field summary lists properties of the object which store type specific metadata

> what the Field Detail is and what that describes

- The field detail describes the intent of each field

> what the Method Summary is and what that describes

- The method summary lists methods of the object which process specific data

> what the Method Detail is and what that describes

- The method detail describes the intent of each method

The `use` link returns all cross-references of the current class to map to other classes which extend, implement, or use it.

Code which generates JavaDoc includes the following annotations:

- @link
- @see
- @serial
- @serialField
- @deprecated
- @param
- @author
- @exception
- @throws
- @linkplain
- @returns
- @since
- @value
- @version

**References**

- [doc2java code generator github repo](https://github.com/BackupTheBerlios/doc2java/)
- [freemarker.template.utility Class ObjectConstructor](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/utility/ObjectConstructor.html)
- [JDK-4473462 : stddoclet: Javadoc fails to document private inner class methods & members](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4473462)
- [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)
- [JavaDoc Overview](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javadoc.html)
- [JavaDoc Man Page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html)
- [JEP 221: Simplified Doclet API](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/221)
- [Maven JavaDoc Plugin: Configuring Custom Javadoc Tags](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/tag-configuration.html)
- [Doclet Overview: Example - Creating and handling custom tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html#customtags)
- [com.sun.javadoc: Interface RootDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/RootDoc.html)
- [What's New in Javadoc 5.0](http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/whatsnew-1.5.0.html)
- [Magento: DocBlock Standard](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/coding-standards/docblock-standard-general.html)
- [NaturalDocs::Parser::JavaDoc - Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/documentation/framedhtml/files/Modules/NaturalDocs/Parser/JavaDoc-pm.html)
- [com.sun.javadoc Class Hierarchy (Doclet API )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/package-tree.html)
- [Commenting in Java (pdf)](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc207h/winter/lectures/javadoc.pdf)
- [OpenJDK Mercurial Repositories](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/)
- [JDK9 Client Mercurial Repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/client/jdk/file/tip/)
- [JavaDoc Search Engine](https://www.javadoc.io/)
- [Maven – Mojo API Specification](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html)
- [MojoDescriptor (Maven Plugin API 3.5.0 API)](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.5.0/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/descriptor/MojoDescriptor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Each constructor is a method used to create an instance of the BigInteger class and can each take different parameters.  This is how Java can differentiate between which constructor you intended to use.  When you create a new BigInteger such as:

```
BigInteger myInt = new Rational(int num1, int num2)
```

Java knows you were using the constructor

```
Rational(int x, int y)
```

by matching the type and order of your passed parameters.  Usually there are mutator and accessor methods to update values which belong to an instance of your class.  Each of the fields are variables which belong to each instance of a BigInteger.  So when you create a new BigInteger, each instance has its own field variables which are specific to the class.

Comment: I don't have trouble with the concept of different constructors by the same name having different parameters. I understand that concept. The part I don't understand is which constructor on the Javadoc page i should use with the parameters structure of Rational(int n) vs Rational (int x, int y). In the constructor Rational(int n) it takes a single integer and Rational(int x, int y) takes two integers. I'm confused which constructor on the Javadoc takes a single integer like Rational(int n) and which constructor takes two integers like Rational(int x, int y).